# Trying to run Java program with classpath; java is not able to find my original compiled class

Tags: java, javac

java noob here. I am trying to compile a run a java program which uses stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar. I am trying to compile this using MacOS terminal. Following are the outputs of various commands

`javac QuestionsToAnswer.java`
This leads to huge list of errors
`QuestionsToAnswer.java:5: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.trees does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
                             ^
QuestionsToAnswer.java:6: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex.TregexMatcher;
                                    ^
...`

So instead I run this:
`javac -cp stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar QuestionsToAnswer.java`
This works as expected and creates a QuestionToAnswer.class file.

Then when I try to run the program
`java QuestionsToAnswer`
It gives me the following error:
`Error: Unable to initialize main class QuestionsToAnswer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree`

To fix this I add the classpath to the java command so that it is able to find the `Tree` Class from stanford's library
`java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar QuestionsToAnswer`
Then it gives me the following error:
`Error: Could not find or load main class QuestionsToAnswer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: QuestionsToAnswer`

After adding the classpath, java is not able to find my original class file which is already compiled and present in the directory. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show the code for your QuestionsToAnswer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar file must be in the classpath because your code uses classes from this jar. So Java must be able to find them.

The directory containing **your** class must **also** be in the classpath otherwise Java can't possibly find it.

```
java -cp .:stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar QuestionsToAnswer
```

on Unix/MacOS, or

```
java -cp .;stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar QuestionsToAnswer
```

on Windows.

Comment: wow this fixed it... Thanks for the help... Now I feel that this question is dumb. Should I delete it?

Comment: No. Accept the answer, so that JB Nizet gets credit.