# stanford corenlp java class jar file compile missing '.'

Tags: java, windows, jar

I haven't used java in like 8 years but I don't remember anyone talking about jar files.

I'm trying to do the NER process like at the link [NER example java code](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html).  I copied their example java class, NERPipelineDemo at the link.  When I tried to compile the NERPipelineDemo , it had errors, and it looked like it needed me to download the NER package from the website.  I downloaded it at [download stanford corenlp](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html) (red download button), and wound up with a very huge jar file.  I copied the jar file to the dir that my NERPipelineDemo.java is in and added an import at the top.  This is the top of the program found at the example link, with comment added for the import line I added.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;  //I added this line to example found online
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NERPipelineDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner");
    // example customizations (these are commented out but you can uncomment them to see the results

    // disable fine grained ner
    // props.setProperty("ner.applyFineGrained", "false");

    // customize fine grained ner
    // props.setProperty("ner.fine.regexner.mapping", "example.rules");
    // props.setProperty("ner.fine.regexner.ignorecase", "true");

    // add additional rules, customize TokensRegexNER annotator
    // props.setProperty("ner.additional.regexner.mapping", "example.rules");
    // props.setProperty("ner.additional.regexner.ignorecase", "true");

    // add 2 additional rules files ; set the first one to be case-insensitive
    // props.setProperty("ner.additional.regexner.mapping", "ignorecase=true,example_one.rules;example_two.rules");

    // set document date to be a specific date (other options are explained in the document date section)
    // props.setProperty("ner.docdate.useFixedDate", "2019-01-01");

    // only run rules based NER
    // props.setProperty("ner.rulesOnly", "true");

    // only run statistical NER
    // props.setProperty("ner.statisticalOnly", "true");

    // set up pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // make an example document
    CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument("Joe Smith is from Seattle.");
    // annotate the document
    pipeline.annotate(doc);
    // view results
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("entities found");
    for (CoreEntityMention em : doc.entityMentions())
      System.out.println("\tdetected entity: \t"+em.text()+"\t"+em.entityType());
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("tokens and ner tags");
    String tokensAndNERTags = doc.tokens().stream().map(token -> "("+token.word()+","+token.ner()+")").collect(
        Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(tokensAndNERTags);
  }

}
```

I didn't process the .jar file at all after I downloaded it because I searched online and it looks like I can just refer to it in a java program.

So when I try to compile the program, I have 4 errors now instead of 6:

```
NERPipelineDemo.java:3: error: '.' expected
import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;
               ^
NERPipelineDemo.java:3: error: ';' expected
import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;
                ^
NERPipelineDemo.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;
                       ^
NERPipelineDemo.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;
                        ^
4 errors
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what the missing '.' is.  The filename is stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar.

I copied the example code from the NER website exactly as shown.

Any ideas what it could be?

Update: I did find another [question online for stanford corenlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524205/trying-to-run-java-program-with-classpath-java-is-not-able-to-find-my-original), and I tried doing what they do, and get the error

```
"Could not find or load main class NERPipelineDemo.java"
```

I also saw [steps to use official release](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html), but they aren't talking about the jar file I got at the download link/button.  I think what they are talking about is the github zip download.

**Update2 (project build/setup info):
In C:\Users\Michele\Documents I have:

```
stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar (downloaded from link above, red button)
 NERPipelineDemo.java (copied exactly from https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html and named as shown)
```

At my Documents directory command prompt, I tried javac NERPipelineDemo.java, but first error list was

```
C:\Users\Michele\Documents>javac NERPipelineDemo.java
NERPipelineDemo.java:4: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
^
NERPipelineDemo.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    ^
  symbol:   class StanfordCoreNLP
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
NERPipelineDemo.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
                                   ^
  symbol:   class StanfordCoreNLP
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
NERPipelineDemo.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument("Joe Smith is from Seattle.");
    ^
  symbol:   class CoreDocument
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
NERPipelineDemo.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument("Joe Smith is from Seattle.");
                           ^
  symbol:   class CoreDocument
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
NERPipelineDemo.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    for (CoreEntityMention em : doc.entityMentions())
         ^
  symbol:   class CoreEntityMention
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
6 errors
```

That's when I tried adding the 
//import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*; //added to NERPipelineDemo.java

Then it had the error in this question's subject:

```
C:\Users\Michele\Documents>javac NERPipelineDemo.java
NERPipelineDemo.java:3: error: '.' expected
import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;
               ^
NERPipelineDemo.java:3: error: ';' expected
import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;
                ^
NERPipelineDemo.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;
                       ^
NERPipelineDemo.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.*;
                        ^
4 errors
```

Then I was thinking I wasn't using the jar right, so I tried what was recommend at the stackoverflow link at my Documents command line,

```
java -cp .;stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline
```

and get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline
```

I'm sure I'm not sure what the process for using the jar file and/or working with java since I'm pretty rusty, and there's a lot of new api usage I'm not used to here.

I'm just trying to feed a string to the stanford library to get the nlp processed string as usable output (NERPipelineDemo, tokens and ner tags).

***Update3 (after response)
I removed the added import to NERPipelineDemo.java and compiled with and get errors, and corrected the command in Update2:

```
javac -cp .;stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar NERPipelineDemo.java
NERPipelineDemo.java:4: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
^
NERPipelineDemo.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    ^
  symbol:   class StanfordCoreNLP
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
NERPipelineDemo.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
                                   ^
  symbol:   class StanfordCoreNLP
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
NERPipelineDemo.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument("Joe Smith is from Seattle.");
    ^
  symbol:   class CoreDocument
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
NERPipelineDemo.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument("Joe Smith is from Seattle.");
                           ^
  symbol:   class CoreDocument
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
NERPipelineDemo.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    for (CoreEntityMention em : doc.entityMentions())
         ^
  symbol:   class CoreEntityMention
  location: class NERPipelineDemo
6 errors
```

I'm not sure what to do about this.  I'm not used to using api's.  Do I need to add more than one cp for that jar file? Shouldn't the one cp cover it all?

Comment: You don't import file names. You import classes from packages. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html. And you make sure the jar file containing those classes is in the classpath when compiling, and when running, the application.

Comment: So my class that uses the jar is NERPipelineDemo.  I tried using that and got the basically same newer error, "Could not find or load main class NERPipelineDemo". Are you saying I need to replace NERPipelineDemo with the class I need to use from the jar file, in my NERPipelineDemo class?

Comment: You got this error when doing what? Post the exact command you executed, tell precisely where the relevant files/directories are located, and post the exact and complete error message. Java is a compiled language. You can't execute .java files. They must be compiled first. Once compiled, you start the program by specifying the name of the class. Not the name of the .java source file.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet.  I added Update2 to the original question.

Comment: Your `javac` command failed. So your code was not compiled. So you can't possibly execute the code. Put back the code as it was before you changed the imports. Then recompile it by passing the correct class path (using the -cp option). Then, when it's successfully compiled, you can run it (and you still need to pass the correct classpath).

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. I added update3 above to the question.

Comment: This jar file doesn't contain the classes you're using. I know nothing about Stanford NLP, but you need other jars in the classpath. And indeed, the instructions at https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html show that all the jars must be in the classpath.

Comment: I wound up Download CoreNLP 3.9.2" at https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html. This downloads a zip file called stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05. I wound up using that with the command line use of that.